# When is Fairy Tail Season 3 release date?

Tags: fairy-tail

I want to know when season 3 is going to be released cuz i watched the trailer and i am waiting for it to be aired

Comment: Sorry, but [questions related to future release date are considered off-topic because even though they're already known, *we're not news outlet*, and the question won't be useful anymore after it's released](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/876/should-we-reopen-questions-about-future-unannounced-events-once-the-event-is-a/878#878). Also, you can just search "fairy tail season 3 release date" on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually next season (Fall 2018). As for the official release date, it's October 6-7 (Japan/EU release date).